# Master-detail grid with 2 dataTable (C# & DevExpress)

Tags: c#, devexpress, master-detail

I try to programmatically code 2 dataTable into Master-Detail grid. Unfortunately is been a week, I try to google the solution and i still fail. 
 I using c# and DevExpress, I manage to set the additional Level1 as gridView2.
The main is the gridview1 and all which is under gridContorl1. Below is the code I did, and seeking advise hope i manage proceed this final step of my experiment program.
The main table is tableSalesOrder & the detail tale is tableDetail. How to relation the tableSalesOrder and tableDetail, when select the tableSalesOrder ItemCode, the tableDetail will only show the ItemCode under Master-Detail view grid

```
    private void btnLoadSO_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LoadOutstandingSO();
        LoadDetailDS();
        gridControl1.DataSource = tableSalesOrder;
    }

   private void LoadOutstandingSO()
    {
        if (tableSalesOrder == null)
            tableSalesOrder = new DataTable("dtSO");
        else
            tableSalesOrder.Clear();

        string sqlSelect2a = "select 0 AS [Check], k.ItemCode, k.[Data Count], l2.Description, l2.ItemGroup, l2.ItemType,"
            + " CASE WHEN l2.CostingMethod = 0 THEN 'Fixed Cost' WHEN l2.CostingMethod=1 THEN 'Weighted Average'"
            + " WHEN l2.CostingMethod=2 THEN 'F.I.F.O' WHEN l2.CostingMethod=3 THEN 'L.I.F.O' ELSE 'Most Recently' END AS [CostingMethod],"
            + " k.UOM, k.Location, K.[Purchased Qty],K.[Sold Qty], K.[Adj Qty], K.[Total Qty], l.BalQty, l2.Desc2, l2.Discontinued, l2.IsActive"
            + " from (Select g.ItemCode, count(*) as [Data Count], g.UOM, g.Location,"
            + " Sum(g.InQty) as [Purchased Qty], Sum(g.OutQty) as [Sold Qty], SUM(g.AdjQty) as [Adj Qty],"
            + " Sum((g.InQty - g.OutQty) + g.AdjQty) as [Total Qty]"
            + " From (Select ivd.ItemCode as ItemCode, ivd.UOM, ivd.Location, 0 as [InQty], ivd.Qty as [OutQty], 0 as [AdjQty]"
            + " From IV ak Join IVDtl ivd on ak.DocKey = ivd.DocKey where ak.Cancelled = 'F'";
        string sqlSelect3a = " Union All"
            + " Select csd.ItemCode as ItemCode, csd.UOM, csd.Location, 0 as [InQty], csd.Qty as [OutQty], 0 as [AdjQty]"
            + " From CS ak Join CSDtl csd on ak.DocKey = csd.DocKey where ak.Cancelled = 'F'";
        string sqlSelect4a = " Union All"
            + " Select pid.ItemCode as ItemCode, pid.UOM, pid.Location, pid.Qty as [InQty], 0 as [OutQty], 0 as [AdjQty]"
            + " From PI ak Join PIDtl pid on ak.DocKey = pid.DocKey where ak.Cancelled = 'F'";
        string sqlSelect5a = " Union All"
            + " Select cpd.ItemCode as ItemCode, cpd.UOM, cpd.Location, cpd.Qty as [InQty], 0 as [OutQty], 0 as [AdjQty]"
            + " From CP ak Join CPDtl cpd on ak.DocKey = cpd.DocKey where ak.Cancelled = 'F'";
        string sqlSelect6a = " Union All"
            + " Select adjd.ItemCode as ItemCode, adjd.UOM, adjd.Location, 0 as [InQty], 0 as [OutQty], adjd.Qty as [AdjQty]"
            + " From ADJ ak Join ADJDTL adjd on ak.DocKey = adjd.DocKey where ak.Cancelled = 'F'";
        string sqlSelect2b = ") g join Item z on g.ItemCode=z.ItemCode where z.StockControl='T'";
        string sqlSelect2c = " Group By g.ItemCode, g.UOM, g.Location) k"
                        + " join ItemBalQty l on k.ItemCode=l.ItemCode and k.UOM=l.UOM and k.Location=l.Location"
                        + " join Item l2 on k.ItemCode=l2.ItemCode";

        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection conn = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(mydbset.ConnectionString);
        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand sqlCmd = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand();
        sqlCmd.Connection = conn;

        BCE.AutoCount.SearchFilter.SearchCriteria crit1a = new BCE.AutoCount.SearchFilter.SearchCriteria();
        BCE.AutoCount.SearchFilter.SearchCriteria crit1b = new BCE.AutoCount.SearchFilter.SearchCriteria();
        crit1a.AddFilter(ucDate.Filter);
        crit1b.AddFilter(ucItem.Filter);

        string critSQL1a = crit1a.BuildSQL(sqlCmd);
        string critSQL1b = crit1b.BuildSQL(sqlCmd);

        if (critSQL1a != "")
            sqlSelect2a += " AND " + critSQL1a + sqlSelect3a +" AND " + critSQL1a
                    + sqlSelect4a + " AND " + critSQL1a + sqlSelect5a + " AND " + critSQL1a
                    + sqlSelect6a + " AND " + critSQL1a + sqlSelect2b;
        else
            sqlSelect2a += sqlSelect3a + sqlSelect4a + sqlSelect5a + sqlSelect6a + sqlSelect2b;

        if (critSQL1b != "")
            sqlSelect2a += " AND " + critSQL1b + sqlSelect2c;
        else
            sqlSelect2a += sqlSelect2c;

        string sqlSelect = sqlSelect2a;

        sqlCmd.CommandText = sqlSelect + " ORDER BY ItemCode";

        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter adpt = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd);

        try
        {
            adpt.Fill(tableSalesOrder);
        }
        catch (BCE.Application.AppException ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }

    private void LoadDetailDS()
    {
        if (tableDetail == null)
            tableDetail = new DataTable("dtDT");
        else
            tableDetail.Clear();

        string sqlSelect2be = "select ak.ItemCode, ak.UOM, ak.Location, ak.DocDate, ak.DocNo, ak.Qty, ak.UnitPrice from"
            + " (select g.ItemCode, g.UOM, g.Location, ak.DocDate, ak.DocNo, g.Qty, g.UnitPrice"
            + " from PI ak right join PIDTL g on ak.DocKey=g.DocKey"; 
        string sqlSelect3be = " union all"
            + " select g.ItemCode, g.UOM, g.Location, ak.DocDate, ak.DocNo, g.Qty , g.UnitPrice"
            + " from CP ak right join CPDTL g on ak.DocKey=g.DocKey";
        string sqlSelect4be = ") ak JOIN Item z on z.ItemCode=ak.ItemCode where z.StockControl='T'";


        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection conn2 = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(mydbset.ConnectionString);
        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand sqlCmd2 = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand();
        sqlCmd2.Connection = conn2;

        BCE.AutoCount.SearchFilter.SearchCriteria crit2be = new BCE.AutoCount.SearchFilter.SearchCriteria();
        BCE.AutoCount.SearchFilter.SearchCriteria crit3be = new BCE.AutoCount.SearchFilter.SearchCriteria();
        crit2be.AddFilter(ucDate.Filter);
        crit3be.AddFilter(ucItem.Filter);

        string critSQL2be = crit2be.BuildSQL(sqlCmd2); 
        string critSQL3be = crit3be.BuildSQL(sqlCmd2);

        if (critSQL3be != "")
            sqlSelect2be += " WHERE " + critSQL3be + sqlSelect3be + " WHERE " + critSQL3be + sqlSelect4be;
        else
            sqlSelect2be += sqlSelect3be + sqlSelect4be;


        if (critSQL2be != "")
            sqlSelect2be += " AND " + critSQL2be;

        sqlCmd2.CommandText = sqlSelect2be + " order by ItemCode, DocDate, DocNo";

        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter adpt = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd2);

        try
        {
            adpt.Fill(tableDetail);
        }
        catch (BCE.Application.AppException ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To locate detail rows by a given master row, you need to add the [relationship](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dbwcse3d.aspx) between these tables in the data set. The relationship defines columns by which a detail row is associated with its master row.

XtraGrid can automatically retrieve data for the detail view from the relationship if the detail level name matches the relationship name. You can assign the level name using the [level designer](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument912) or [programmatically](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument11225).

Moreover, XtraGrid can automatically populate detail levels if the DataSet have relationships and the [ShowOnlyPredefinedDetails](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridGridControl_ShowOnlyPredefinedDetailstopic) option is set to **false**.

Comment: I will try it out for your advice, and come back to of my result. Thank you.

Comment: Hi Uranus, finally I made it. First step I create a data set for both data table. and relation it. After the ShowOnlyPredefinedDetails option is set to false.
 The result is work nice, now I just need to touch up gridView2 double click method as the final step, Thank you for the guide.